# Player gazebo ERROR protobuf missing requiered position,orientation

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am getting a lot of errors when I am trying conect player and gazebo (1.4.0).
When I run playerv or whatever other client pf player I getting the follow message:
Encounterd strings containinf invalid UTF-8 while parsing protocol buffer. Stirngs must contain inly UTF-8; yse the "bytes" type for waw bytes.
libprotobud ERROR google : Cna't parse message of type "gazebo.msgs.Pose" because it is missing requierd field: position, orientarion.

I have compiled player and gazebo several times but the problem persists.
thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1329/player-gazebo-error-protobuf-missing-requiered-position,orientation/) by [efolgado](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/206/efolgado/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-02-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This type of error looks like multiple conflicting version of gazebo are in use. First place to look is your environment variables.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0